# Invoke iOS app unit test from shell script?

Tags: ios

If a DevOps engineer wants to invoke your iOS app unit tests from a shell script(App is in production), how can we do that? Objective is, a devops script should be able to trigger your unit tests and know if your tests pass or fail.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
xcodebuild \
  -workspace MyAwesomeApp.xcworkspace \
  -scheme MyAwesomeApp \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.1' \
  test
```

Further info [here](https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/running-tests-from-the-terminal/).

The result of something like:

```
xcodebuild -workspace WORKSPACE -scheme SCHEME -sdk iphonesimulator -destination DESTINATION test
```

**Should equal 0** if everything went well.

Comment: Thanks Durdu, just one question your source code is not in local system then what would be the approach?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need but seems like you should look into remote access CI, CD -  teamviewer/ Fastlane / Jenkins/ piplines /gitlab